# Needing to use the view to search into a deep object and access keys

Tags: angularjs

I have already completed this using a function in the controller, however I **have to** do this only within the view.

```
<th style="border:2px solid black; padding:10px;" 
    ng-repeat="(key,x) in vm.tableData track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in x >
    {{key}}
  </div>
</th>
```

i need to make this line in the html search a deep object and get the keys, the vm.tableData looks like this :

```
240:{
      G1:{data},
      G2:{data},      
      G3:{data},
    },
309:{
      G1:{data},
      G2:{data},      
      G3:{data},
    }
```

I need the table headers to equal `"G1","G2","G3"` etc

bear in mind Ido not need the headers for how many pieces of data I have.

I cannot find a solution to this and any ideas will be a big help.

Comment: if the keys are not dynamic, it's enough to have `(key,x) in vm.tableData[240]` and you can remove your inner `<div>` (just render the `{{key}}`)

Comment: as much as i would of loved to of been able to do that, i am using a mock firebase database, the data on our mock is not the same as our live version, and so i cannot do this

Comment: I can offer you a _hack_ with `ng-show="$first"`, which will limit your selection to  only one set of headers: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8IdDvaZUy5HMuSiNxQUa?p=preview). You need something else to wrap around `<th>` to get that dynamic key first (I used `<tr>`), but you can't repeat it with `ng-repeat`, so I limited it with `ng-show`

Comment: Afraid to say that `ng-show="$first"` has been tried and failed, as it fills out 1 of the 10 columns with G1,G2,G3 as its header

Comment: I gave you a working example

Comment: I just spotted that. absolute genius , thank you very much. If you submit that as the answer i will upvote it. Are there any setbacks to $first, as i cannot think of any within this instance